# Group array alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to group array by first letter of lastnames.

For the moment I managed to classify the lastnames alphabetically but not to group them by letter

```
$alumnis_array_lastname = array();

foreach( $alumnis_list_lastname as $key => $post ) {
    $word = explode( ' ', $post->post_title, 2 );
    $lastname = '';

    if (strlen($word[1]) == 1) {
        $lastname = $word[0];
    } else {
        $lastname = $word[1];
    }

    $firstname = $word[0];

    $alumnis_array_lastname[] = array('firstname'=>$firstname, 'lastname'=>$lastname);
}

uasort($alumnis_array_lastname, function($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a['lastname'], $b['lastname']);
});
```

For the moment alla work fine, I managed to sort my entire array alphabetically.

```
array (
    [0] => Array (
        [firstname] => Rachel
        [lastname] => Aaron
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [firstname] => David
        [lastname] => Abril
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [firstname] => Franck
        [lastname] => Bower
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [firstname] => Stacy
        [lastname] => Catal
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [firstname] => Anthony
        [lastname] => Dawson
    )
    [5] => Array (
        [firstname] => Katty
        [lastname] => Derren
    )
)
```

But I would like somehting like that :

```
array (
    [A] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [firstname] => Rachel
            [lastname] => Aaron    
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [firstname] => David
            [lastname] => Abril  
        )
    )
    [B] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [firstname] => Franck
            [lastname] => Bower  
        )
    )
    [C] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [firstname] => Stacy
            [lastname] => Catal   
        )
    )
    [D] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [firstname] => Anthony
            [lastname] => Dawson   
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [firstname] => Katty
            [lastname] => Derren 
        )
    )
)
```

How can I do ? Can I hase some help please ?

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward to achieve. You seem to already know how to build arrays. Now all you need is to search for getting the first character of a string in PHP.

Comment: you can do something like $list_alumnis_lastname[$name[0]][] = $name;, but create an empty array first if it hasn't existed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the first character as a key to group data in an array.

But, you first need to sort the incomming array with [`usort()`](https://php.net/usort) and [`strcmp()`](https://php.net/strcmp).

```
usort($name, fn($a, $b) => strcmp($a['lastname'], $b['lastname'])); // PHP 7.4
usort($name, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['lastname'], $b['lastname']); });
```

Example:

```
$users = [
    ['firstname' => 'Steve',   'lastname'  => 'Naghavi'],
    ['firstname' => 'Trent',   'lastname'  => 'Reznor'],
    ['firstname' => 'Eskil',   'lastname'  => 'Simonsson'],
    ['firstname' => 'David',   'lastname'  => 'Abril'],
    ['firstname' => 'Rachel',  'lastname'  => 'Aaron'],
    ['firstname' => 'Franck',  'lastname'  => 'Bower'],
    ['firstname' => 'Stacy',   'lastname'  => 'Catal'],
    ['firstname' => 'Katty',   'lastname'  => 'Derren'],
    ['firstname' => 'Anthony', 'lastname'  => 'Dawson'],
];

// sort input
usort($users, function($a, $b) { 
    return strcmp($a['lastname'], $b['lastname']); 
});

// group data
$output = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $letter = $user['lastname'][0]; // get first char
    $output[$letter][] = $user;     // group
}

print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Rachel
                    [lastname] => Aaron
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => David
                    [lastname] => Abril
                )

        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Franck
                    [lastname] => Bower
                )

        )

    [C] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Stacy
                    [lastname] => Catal
                )

        )

    [D] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Anthony
                    [lastname] => Dawson
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Katty
                    [lastname] => Derren
                )

        )

    [N] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Steve
                    [lastname] => Naghavi
                )

        )

    [R] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Trent
                    [lastname] => Reznor
                )

        )

    [S] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Eskil
                    [lastname] => Simonsson
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning here, that sorting the input data is not necessary for the _grouping_ part of the algorithm to work, put only for having those `A`, `B`, `C`, … keys in the correct alphabetical order in the result. Which could also be achieved by applying `ksort` to the result afterwards. (_Could_ make a performance difference, if the number of input records is _huge_.)

Comment: Right @CBroe. But, it still necessary to sort out the elements inside (ex for `Derren` and `Dawson`).

Comment: Okay, yes, if those need to be in correct order as well, then sorting upfront indeed makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```php
$names = [
    [
        'firstname' => 'Rachel',
        'lastname'  => 'Aaron'
    ],
    [
        'firstname' => 'David',
        'lastname'  => 'Abril'
    ],
    [
        'firstname' => 'Franck',
        'lastname'  => 'Bower'
    ],
    [
        'firstname' => 'Stacy',
        'lastname'  => 'Catal'
    ],
    [
        'firstname' => 'Anthony',
        'lastname'  => 'Dawson'
    ],
    [
        'firstname' => 'Katty',
        'lastname'  => 'Derren'
    ],
    [
        'firstname' => 'Steve',
        'lastname'  => 'Naghavi'
    ],
    [
        'firstname' => 'Trent',
        'lastname'  => 'Reznor'
    ],
    [
        'firstname' => 'Eskil',
        'lastname'  => 'Simonsson'
    ],        
];

$output = [];
foreach ($names as $name)
{
    $current_letter = substr($name['lastname'], 0, 1);
    $output[$current_letter][] = $name;
}
print_r($output);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Rachel
                    [lastname] => Aaron
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => David
                    [lastname] => Abril
                )
        )
    [B] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Franck
                    [lastname] => Bower
                )

        )
    [C] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Stacy
                    [lastname] => Catal
                )
        )
    [D] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Anthony
                    [lastname] => Dawson
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Katty
                    [lastname] => Derren
                )
        )
    [N] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Steve
                    [lastname] => Naghavi
                )
        )
    [R] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Trent
                    [lastname] => Reznor
                )
        )
    [S] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [firstname] => Eskil
                    [lastname] => Simonsson
                )
        )
)
```